# Plotting graphs showing precipitation of area on map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, graph

I have precipitation data of an area and I need to create a bar graph or something on the map of the area showing the precipitation. Is there a way I can do it?? I am a beginner so I really don't have an idea about it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have rain-gage data for different months or days, here is a link to Esri help for visualizing data with bar and pie graphs.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/about-symbolizing-layers-to-represent-quantity.htm

Often precipitation data comes as raster data.  For example, the total amount of rainfall for a given year over an area.  If you have these data you can't graph the data.